# Why asp.net core mvc still connect to the same database even though I change the database name in the connection string?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I export a database named "aspnet-SimpleBank-C2FC2762-4DD0-4E9A-90C2-C876AA53348C" as SimpleBankDatabase.bacpac using SQL Server Management Studio. Then import SimpleBankDatabase.bacpac into a database as SimpleBank. I change the connection string in my application to connect to SimpleBank but the application still connect to the old one because I try to add insert some data into the database through the application.

I try to copy the "SimpleBank" to the folder that stores "aspnet-SimpleBank-C2FC2762-4DD0-4E9A-90C2-C876AA53348C" but it still does not work.

```
The first connection string is commented.

    {
    "ConnectionStrings": {
    //"DefaultConnection": "Server= 
    (localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=
    aspnet-SimpleBank-C2FC2762-4DD0-4E9A-90C2- C876AA53348C;
    Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

    "DefaultConnection": "Server= 

   (localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=SimpleBank;
   Trusted_Connection=True;
   MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
   },
   "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
    }
```

The database name is completely different but the application still connect to the old database.

Comment: JSON doesn’t have comments. Remove the line, don’t try to comment it out. If that’s the default generated database I assume parsing the settings fails and a default connection string is created.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you have here is you are using `localdb` in this line

```
(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb
```

So if you have sql server change to your sql server address to connect to the db.

Comment: I install MS SQL Server 2017 Express and change the server name to Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS. It still connect to the old database on localdb. The application behaviour is weird. Only the imported database names in the connection string allow the application to connect to the old database.

Comment: I think you can delete the bin and obj folder to clean the cache

Comment: I just deleted the bind and obj folder, but it still connect to the old database. Is there a way to configure Visual Studio not to use LocalDB? I remember I used to see it somewhere but I cannot find it again.

Comment: do you used user secret in your project?

Comment: No, but I use individual user accounts for asp.net core mvc template. The database is created automatically when I register a user.

Comment: Thank you, Tony Ngo. I found the problem. I did not update the connection string in another file.

Answer (score 1):

The simple thing is that if you have changed the connection string to a different database and if the string is correctly written it will definitely work ( even if it is wrong the exception will be thrown ). Taking consideration that you have correctly commented the first connection string ( which is not shown correct from your post ) I will suggest to check the following.

1. Have you overridden the connection string in a different place ?
2. Check your `ConfigureServices`method (or where you read the connection string) and put a debug point there to get the working connection string.
3. If you have any `Environment` specific `appsetting` file and the connection string is written there also what you forgot to change.

Comment: I check ConfigureServices. The connection string is correctly referenced. It still does not work even though I use proper database instead of localDB.

Comment: Thank you, Anadi. I found the problem. I did not update the connection string in another file.